# Getting Error while building script using ant

Tags: ant, junit, jenkins

I have generated build.xml for my test project. When i fire ant main command it is giving error-

```
Jenkins\workspace\\TestProject\src\com\example\testproject\TestProject.java:2: error: package android.test does not exist
    [javac] import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestMobileBankApp\TestProject\src\com\example\testproject\TestProject.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class TestProject extends AndroidTestCase {
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class AndroidTestCase
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Exception.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Override.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Target.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Retention.class)]]
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.class)]]
    [javac] [checking com.example.testproject.TestProject]
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestProject\src\com\example\testproject\TestProject.java:8: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] [loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Throwable.class)]]
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestProject\src\com\example\testproject\TestProject.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         super.setUp();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable super
    [javac]   location: class TestProject
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestMobileBankApp\TestProject\src\com\example\testproject\TestProject.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         assertEquals(true, true);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   method assertEquals(boolean,boolean)
    [javac]   location: class TestProject
    [javac] [total 719ms]
    [javac] 5 errors
```

Same error is coming on Windows 7 and jenkins. 
I have tried with changing my jdk path but it is not working.

Comment: What i am trying is- To generate junit report on jenkins, For that i have written build.xml. When i navigate to directory and fire ant main command it is showing error-    [javac]         assertEquals(true, true);
  [javac]         ^
  [javac]   symbol:   method assertEquals(boolean,boolean)
  [javac]   location: class TestProject  \build.xml:26: Compile failed;

Comment: Please help me on this, I am new to all this, I would be grateful if any one is having solution.

Comment: You're having an issue with an Ant script, but you didn't post your Ant script. You're getting _symbol not found_ and _package doesn't exist_. These point to missing jar files in your `<javac>` task. Look at your classpath. Post your `build.xml`, and we can give you more help.

Answer (score 1):

It is the  issue with jar files.You need to add the jar files in the classpath while compiling.Here is an example of adding an jar file in the classpath of your javac task.

```
<path id="selenium.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/selenium">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
</path>
```

```
                 <classpath refid="selenium.classpath" />

    </javac>
```

Here i have placed all required  jars in the selenium folder under the root directory(base directory)

Comment: <target name="compile">
  <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" deprecation="false">
   <classpath refid="selenium.classpath" />
   

  </javac>
 </target>

Answer (score 0):

```
<path id="selenium.classpath">
<fileset dir="${basedir}/selenium">
    <include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
<pathelement location="${bin.dir}" />
</path>

<target name="compile" >
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" deprecation="false">
        <classpath refid="selenium.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

That was the partial answer.here is the correct code